# how to fix the error ([winerror 2] The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pydub

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from pydub import AudioSegment
import pydub.playback as playback

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Music Player")

# Create a variable to store the currently loaded audio
current_audio = None

def play_music():
    global current_audio
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Mp3 files", "*.mp3")])
    if file_path:
        if current_audio:
            playback.stop()  # Stop any currently playing audio
        current_audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file_path)
        playback.play(current_audio)

def stop_music():
    global current_audio
    if current_audio:
        playback.stop()

def set_position(value):
    global current_audio
    if current_audio:
        # Convert the value to milliseconds
        position = int(float(value) * len(current_audio))
        if position >= 0 and position <= len(current_audio):
            playback.stop()  # Stop the audio
            playback.play(current_audio[position:])  # Play from the new position

play_button = tk.Button(window, text="Play", command=play_music)
stop_button = tk.Button(window, text="Stop", command=stop_music)

seek_label = tk.Label(window, text="Seek Position:")
seek_slider = ttk.Scale(window, from_=0.0, to=1.0, length=300, orient="horizontal", command=set_position)

seek_label.pack()
seek_slider.pack()
play_button.pack()
stop_button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

In this code block "current_audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file_path)" gives me error
([winerror 2] The system cannot find the file specified)

I was making a Simple music playback in python with ChatGPT This code is given by chatgpt
but im not able to debug this problem

Comment: Have you tried printing out `file_path` to see if it's what you expect? Have you tried running `AudioSegment.from_mp3(<correct path>)` in an interactive environment (like IDLE/`python -i`) to see if it will raise an error?

Comment: Yes i have tested it in python's stock IDLE and it shows that there is no pydub module in my PC but i have installed it.
So, basically stock IDLE and VS are giving two different errors